# Help! Can not increase the text size in the Python Console

Tags: interface, command-line

I'm running Blender 2.77 on a MacBook Air with OSX 10.11.6 with just the built-in keyboard and trackpad (I mostly script stuff). When I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> it doesn't make the font in the Python console larger, it just shows a string of "===". I've tried all kinds of other two and three-key combinations, but the font never gets bigger.

I'll give a talk introducing Blender scripting to some Python programmers, and I'd really like them to see what's going on there. I'll take any kind of work-around that makes the text bigger without chaning the Python console window size **edit:** *or changing the font size in all the windows at the same time.*

I looked around in preferences and couldn't find an explicit font size for the Python console, but there may be some keyboard mapping I can do?

I bought the computer in the far east and it types in Traditional Chinese as well - I don't know if that influences the settings. Another person with same situation here (MacBook Air, OSX, Chinese Keyboard, Blender) had no problem with it.

[image]

**above:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> just gives equal signs

[image]

**above:** couldn't find anything helpful here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the way blender stores the [screen](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Screen.html) layout you will find the space used by the [console](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.SpaceConsole.html) has a `font_size` property, setting that will get the result you want.

A small script is easier than finding it manually.

```
import bpy

for a in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if a.type == 'CONSOLE':
        a.spaces[0].font_size = 16
```

Alternatively for the *current console*, keep in mind `bpy.context` is by default aliased as `C`:

```
# repeatedly execute until satisfied
C.space_data.font_size += 1
```

Comment: yippie yay yay for Python OK! OK this is a really helpful introduction to screen areas, and it will be a simple but compelling example in my basic talk. Thank you!

Comment: @zeffii nice to see you again, helpful as always!

Answer (score 2):

Go to user preferences

[image]

Look at the DPI setting in system, under general

[image]

Change the resolution

[image]

Comment: OK got it (in my version it's called `System` not general). But it's a global thing and makes the UI look ridiculously crammed and cartoonish. I'll consider it, but I really need something that only affects the Python console. Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh It might be ok on a projector, since you might want the audience to be able to see the UI

Comment: I like this answer, but I see you don't want it to effect everything.  So try: With the mouse hovering over the console pane, hold down ctrl and scroll with the middle mouse button to resize.

Comment: Thanks @10Replies but I've already given one of these in the same room and I know just what I need. I need that text to be bigger without screwing up the whole thing. The scripting window has a nice font size control right there, but I'd like to show and use the interactive Python console as well.

Answer (score 2):

In the help text it says: 
"Zoom:                Ctrl +/-, Ctrl-Wheel"
I see you tried ctrl +/-, but try the scroll wheel.

So, with the mouse hovering over the console pane, hold down ctrl and scroll with the middle mouse button to resize.

Comment: Thanks, but if you read the question you will see I do not have a scroll wheel. I have no problem doing anything else in Blender with my track pad, but I can't believe that a font size in a Python window *exclusively for typing and reading text* would be the one window that requires me to go out and invest in a 3-button mouse!! That would be ironic considering I've never needed nor used a mouse with Blender!

Comment: @uhoh Can't you scroll with a touchpad?

Comment: If there is something scrollable and the cursor is over it, two fingers scrolls. But I don't have a hard-wired, dedicated *scroll wheel*. If the cursor is over the Python console, then two fingers scrolls up and down. It looks like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wyVwZUuKOw